# jQuery - run a function of change() and ready()

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code which run on `.change()`.
But I want to run the same code on jquery `.ready()`, but it is not working.

### **Here is my code:**

```
    jQuery('.nhp-opts-select-hide-below').change(function(){
        var option = jQuery('option:selected', this);
        if(option.data('show').length > 0 || option.data('hide').length > 0){
            jQuery(option.data('show')).each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).closest('tr').is(':hidden')){
                    jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeIn('fast');
                }
            });
            jQuery(option.data('hide')).each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).closest('tr').is(':visible')){
                    jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('fast');
                }
            });

        }else{
            jQuery(option.data('show')).each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).closest('tr').is(':visible')){
                    jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('fast');
                }
            });
            jQuery(option.data('hide')).each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).closest('tr').is(':hidden')){
                    jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeIn('fast');
                }
            });     
        }
    });
```

please tell me how to run the above code on jquery ready??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just call [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) with no arguments. Put that whole thing inside of your ready handler, and then:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.nhp-opts-select-hide-below').change(function(){
        // snip...
    }).change(); // that's it
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to manually trigger the change event on ready.

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('.nhp-opts-select-hide-below').change();
});
```

Comment: you answer was also helpful, +1